# how to run aggregate query in mongodb client on RockMongo or mViewer

Tags: mongodb, database

I've just started using mongo db, I'm using rockmongo client and my ubuntu terminal as another client. I' ve realized the query using group aggregation like this:

```
 db.archiveImpl.group(
 {
   key: {accountID: true, phone: true },
   cond: {'userId': "oiuoifas2309u"},
   reduce: function(object, prev){ },
   initial:{}

 }
```

)

And the above query is not getting run in the `rockmongo` , I initially thought that the query was wrong. and I ran in on the terminal which pulls me the data. So I downloaded and installed `mViewer` and it didn't work either so I believe there is a way to run these kind of queries in mongo web clients

thanks for reading this .

Answer (score 10):

You can run aggregate query in "tools->command" panel in your homepage of rockmongo. 
You may enter query in the input panel like this:

```
{ 
  aggregate : "ns",                                          
  pipeline : [
               ...
             ]                
}
```

That will be ok! I have tried, and it works!

Full Example:

```
{ aggregate : "COLLECTION_NAME",
  pipeline : [
    { $unwind : "$SUB_ARRAY" },
    { $match: {"SUB_ARRAY.field": "value"}},
  ]
}
```