# MongoDB Selection Sort Issue

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, mongodb

my problem is i want to do a Database find (Selection) witz a division in sort. ^^

That looks in my Code like:

```
$return = $db->selectCollection( $category )->find(array("time" > $time_lastweek))->sort(array("rating/count_raitings" => 1,"count_raitings" => 1))->limit(10);
```

I have done this before in SQL (PDO) like this:

```
$last_week = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$category.' WHERE time > :zeit ORDER BY rating/count_raitings ASC, count_raitings ASC LIMIT 10');
        $last_week->execute(array(':zeit' => $time_lastweek));
        $return = $last_week->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

Please can anyone help me. The MongoDB thing wont work for me.

Comment: You can't do that with a `find` query.  You'd have to use the aggregation framework for that.

Comment: And how could i do this in this framework?

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to do this using the agg framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) to do it in the shell (should be straightforward to translate to PHP):

```js
db.category.aggregate([
    // Filter the docs to those where time > time_lastweek
    { $match: {time: {$gt: time_lastweek}}},

    // Identify what to include from each doc, adding a computed field for the division
    { $project: {
        time: 1,
        rating: 1,
        count_raitings: 1,
        div_val: {$divide: ['$rating', '$count_raitings']}
    } },

    // Sort the results
    { $sort: {div_val: 1, count_raitings: 1}},

    // Limit to the top 10
    { $limit: 10 }
])
```

Comment: hhmm, so why my mongodb says: Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoCollection::aggregate() in??

Comment: What version of MongoDB is your server?  The aggregation framework was introduced in v2.2.

Comment: If i do apt-get update on it (debian) it says all is up to date.

Comment: Status says: version "2.2.1"
process "mongod"

Comment: If i put this in my Command of the Rockmongo it says: You should send a valid command ??

Comment: This is a shell command, to do this in RockMongo see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12365444/1259510).